# mod_rewrite with web.config how to activate GET functions?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, web-config

Hello guys so as far as I'm concerned, the web.config file that I own rewrites urls so that instead of showing http://www.site.com/page.php it shows http://www.site.com/page and now GET functions won't work.

Here is the code of web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                    <match url="^(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2">
                    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 3">
                    <match url="^(.*)\.htm$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 4">
                    <match url="^(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?page={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 5">
                    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas on how I can allow the PHP $_GET function?

**Edit: Fixed by changing appendQueryString="false" to appendQueryString="true"
Thank you for helping!**

Comment: No I didn't and it certainly did the trick, thank you so much.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and accept it whenever you can, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done because of "appendQueryString="**false**" so changing the attribute to **true** fixed the problem.